# decrypt function for crypt function php

Tags: php

What is the decrypt function for crypt function in PHP

Thanks
Bharanikumar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

> There is no decrypt function, since crypt() uses a one-way algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

5 seconds of searching stackoverflow:

- [how do I encrypt and then decrypt the text of username and password used in database class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945881/how-do-i-encrypt-and-then-decrypt-the-text-of-username-and-password-used-in-datab)
- [How can I decrypt password string in PHP which was encrypted with crypt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524182/how-can-i-decrypt-password-string-in-php-which-was-encrypted-with-crypt)
- [php mcrypt - decrypting and encrypting files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393203/php-mcrypt-decrypting-and-encrypting-files)
- [Encrypt and Decrypt String With Key PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806682/encrypt-and-decrypt-string-with-key-php)
- [php encrypt and decrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347802/php-encrypt-and-decrypt)

I'm sure google has more. Please do a bit of research before you ask a question, it's not fair to just expect everyone else to do all the thinking for you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot decrypt the [crypt](http://uk.php.net/crypt) function but if you need original string back, use mcrypt_encrypt and [mcrypt_decrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php), and choose key based encryption like MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256